# Do Haskell’s strict folds really use linear space?

Tags: performance, haskell, memory, lazy-evaluation, fold

I thought I understood the basics of fold performance in Haskell, as described in [`foldr`, `foldl`, `foldl'` on the Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27) and many other places.  In particular, I learned that for accumulating functions, one should use `foldl'`, to avoid space leaks, and that the standard library functions are written to respect this.  So I presumed that simple accumulators like `length`, applied to simple lists like `replicate n 1`, should require constant space (or at least sub-linear) in the length of the list.  My intuition was that on sufficiently simple lists, they would behave roughly like a `for` loop in an imperative language.

But today I found that this seems not to hold in practice. For instance, **`length $ replicate n 1` seems to use space linear in `n`.**  In `ghci`:

```
ghci> :set +s
ghci> length $ replicate (10^6) 1
1000000
(0.02 secs, 56,077,464 bytes)
ghci> length $ replicate (10^7) 1
10000000
(0.08 secs, 560,078,360 bytes)
ghci> length $ replicate (10^8) 1
100000000
(0.61 secs, 5,600,079,312 bytes)
ghci> length $ replicate (10^9) 1
1000000000
(5.88 secs, 56,000,080,192 bytes)
```

Briefly, my question is: **Do `length` and other strict folds really use linear space? If so, why? And is it inevitable?**  Below are more details of how I’ve played around trying to understand this, but they’re probably not worth reading — the tl;dr is that the linear-space usage seems to persist whatever variations I try.

(I originally used `sum` as the example function. As Willem Van Onsem points out, that was a badly-chosen example as default instances aren’t actually strict.  However, the main question remains, since as noted below, this occurs with plenty of other functions that really are based on strict folds.)

- Replacing `length` with `foldl' (\n _ -> n+1) 0` appears to make performance worse by a constant factor; space usage still seems to be linear.
- Versions defined with `foldl` and `foldr` had worse memory usage (as expected), but only by a small constant factor, not asymptotically worse (as most discussions seem to suggest).
- Replacing `length` with `sum`, `last`, or other simple accumulators, or with the obvious definitions of these using `foldl'`, also doesn’t seem to change the linear space usage.
- Using `[1..n]` as the test list, and other similar variations, also seems to make no significant difference.
- Switching between the general versions of `sum`, `foldl'`, etc from `Data.Foldable`, the specialised ones in `Data.List`, and local versions defined directly by pattern-matching, also seems to make no difference.
- Compiling instead of working in `ghci` also only seemed to improve space usage by a constant factor.
- Switching between several recent versions of GHC — 8.8.4, 8.10.5, and 9.0.1 — also seemed to make no significant difference.

Comment: `sum` is implemented with `foldr` such that one can use *Peano* numbers for example.

Comment: Space usage can be a bit misleading in Haskell because of garbage collection. In unoptimized code, Haskell will often create large numbers of memory allocations that it could, in theory, immediately garbage collect. So the amount of space needed is constant, but the space isn't reclaimed until it's necessary to do so and thus it appears that linear space is needed.  Willem Van Onsem is correct that `sum` implicitly uses `foldr` (since `sum` uses `foldMap`, which in turn uses `foldr`), so `sum` actually does require linear space.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: really?  `Data.Foldable` suggests otherwise, under [list of strict functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#g:10).  If so, that would explain why using the `foldl'`-based versions improved performance.  But it doesn’t answer my overall question, since the `foldl'`-versions still seemed to be linear-space, as I wrote.

Comment: @PLL: No, it means *provided that the instance is implemented correctly*, that means that you can override `sum`, for example for your own list/vector/array-like structure. For an array for example, we might know that it is finite, and thus then using `foldl` is a good idea. One does not have to work with the `Sum` data type either.

Comment: The `bytes` number reported by ghci is the number of bytes allocated total, not the amount of bytes resident. You can allocate gigabytes and gigabytes and still fit in one kilobyte if everything you allocate gets immediately thrown away. Is it possible that you made this interpretational mistake when concluding that `foldl' (+) 0` takes linear space?

Comment: "Compiling" how? probably without the `-O2`? use `-O2`, then run the standalone executable with "`+RTS -s`" to see the run times (user and GC) and the memory residence. profiling can affect the performance which you try to measure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Do they use linear space" is a slightly unclear question. Usually when we talk about the space an algorithm uses, we're talking about its working set: the maximum amount of memory it needs all at once. "If my computer only had X bytes of memory, could I run this program?" But that's not what GHCI's `:set +s` measures. It measures the sum of all memory allocations made, including those that were cleaned up partway through. And what is the biggest use of memory in your experiment? The list itself, of course.

So you've really just measured the number of bytes that a list of size N takes up. You can confirm this by using `last` instead of `length`, which I hope you'll agree allocates no intermediate results, and is strict. It takes the same amount of memory using your metric as `length` does - `length` does no extra allocation for the sums.

But a bigger problem is that GHCI is not an optimizing compiler. If you care about performance characteristics at all, GHCI is the wrong tool. Instead, use GHC with -O2, and turn on GHC's profiler.

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main = do
  n <- read . head <$> getArgs
  print $ length (replicate (10^n) 1)
```

And running it:

```
$ ghc -O2 -prof -fprof-auto stackoverflow.hs
$ ./stackoverflow 6 +RTS -p
1000000
$ grep "total alloc" stackoverflow.prof
    total alloc =      54,856 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
$ ./stackoverflow 9 +RTS -p
1000000000
$ grep "total alloc" stackoverflow.prof
    total alloc =      55,008 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

we can see that space usage is roughly constant despite a thousand-fold increase in input size.

Will Ness correctly points out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534179/do-haskell-s-strict-folds-really-use-linear-space/68534840#comment121122170_68534179) that `-s` would be a better measuring tool than `-p`.

Answer (score 1):

> Replacing sum with `foldl' (+) 0` here, then performance improves noticeably in both time and space (which is itself a surprise; shouldn’t the standard sum be at least as efficient?) — but only by a constant factor; space usage still seems to be linear.

The sum is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/Data-Foldable.html#sum):

> ```
> sum :: Num a => t a -> a
> sum = getSum #. foldMap Sum
> ```

It thus makes use of the [**`Sum`** data type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum) and its `Monoid` instance such that `mappend = (+)` and `mempty = 0`. `foldMap` works right associative, indeed:

> Map each element of the structure into a monoid, and combine the results with `(<>)`. This **fold is right-associative** and **lazy in the accumulator**. For strict left-associative folds consider `foldMap'` instead.

`foldMap` is thus [implemented with `foldr` [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/Data-Foldable.html#foldMap):

> ```
> foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
> {-# INLINE foldMap #-}
> -- This INLINE allows more list functions to fuse.  See #9848.
> foldMap f = foldr (mappend . f) mempty
> ```

While `foldl'` will indeed have a (much) smaller memory footprint, and likely be more efficient, a reason to work with `foldr` is that for *Peano* numbers for example, one can make use of lazyness, and thus the head normal form will look like `S(…)` where `…` might not be evaluated (yet).

`foldr` can also terminate earlier. If for example you make a sum for a certain algebraic structure, it is possible that we can terminate the looping earlier.

Comment: Thank you; this is interesting and clears up one of the side points I was surprised by.  But using `foldl' (+) 0` directly still appears to use linear-space, and that’s the main question I really would like to understand — I gave `sum` for the example just since I thought that was a simple example of a strict fold.

Comment: @PLL: What if you compile it with `-O2`? Usually using `ghci` is not a good fit for benchmarking, since it will not implement list fusion, etc. You also probably should work with `Int`s instead of the default `Integer` to benchmark, since an `Integer` is eventually an array of bytes to present large numbers, not a fixed-sized `Int` object.

Comment: @PLL: If I implement `sum'` with `sum' = foldl' (+) 0`, and use `main` as `main = print (sum' [0 .. 10^6 :: Int64])` and compiling it with `-O2`, then by using `time`, I get `Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 4496` for `10^6`, `Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 4488` for `10^7` and `Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 4560` for `10^8`. So it looks like it does not grow, or at least not significantly.